# getting the time before the contact issue date SQL Query

Tags: sql

I am comparing two time column in the my file.
What I need to do is to compare the timestamp from order_status table and compare it to the contact table - contact_time.

From the contact table, i need to be able to get the timestamp before the contact_time for each order_id.

Sample:

```
Order_ID    Contact_Time
1           12/24/2019  12:25:00 AM
```

The query should show:

```
Order_ID    Order_Status_ID  Status_Description  
1           3                desc3
```

Since based from the contact_time, the last timestamp for

```
order 1 is: 12/24/2019  12:10:00 AM
```

I only need to show the order_ID, order_status_ID and status_description.

here are the three table:

```
SELECT 
ORDER_ID, 
ORDER_STATUS_ID

FROM ORDER_STATUS
INNER JOIN META_STATUS ON ORDER_STATUS.ORDER_STATUS_ID = META_STATUS.META_STATUS_ID
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT ORDER_STATUS.ORDER_ID, MAX(ORDER_STATUS.TIMESTAMP) MAX_TIME FROM ORDER_STATUS INNER JOIN CONTACT
       ON ORDER_STATUS.ORDER_ID = CONTACT.ORDER_ID
       WHERE CONTACT.CONTACT_TIME > ORDER_STATUS.TIMESTAMP) X
on x.ORDER_ID = ORDER_STATUS.ORDER_ID and ORDER_STATUS.TIMESTAMP = x.MAX_TIME
```

Hope someone can help me fix my code.

Thanks!

Comment: That image doesn't display in a readable way. It's gonna be hard to help you unless you provide those sample tables as **formatted text**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT os.ORDER_ID
       ,os.ORDER_STATUS_ID,
       ,ms.STATUS_DESCRIPTION
  FROM ORDER_STATUS AS os
 INNER JOIN META_STATUS AS ms
       ON os.ORDER_STATUS_ID = ms.META_STATUS_ID
 INNER JOIN (
       SELECT os.ORDER_ID
              ,MAX(os.TIMESTAMP) MAX_TIME 
         FROM ORDER_STATUS AS os
        INNER JOIN CONTACT AS c
              ON os.ORDER_ID = c.ORDER_ID
        WHERE c.CONTACT_TIME > os.TIMESTAMP) x
           ON x.ORDER_ID = os.ORDER_ID 
          AND os.TIMESTAMP = x.MAX_TIME
```

Comment: I did a few edits cause it didn't translate directly from my copy paste. Sorry.

Comment: Hello! theschmidly, thanks for you response. I pasted the code in MS Access but i got this issue - Syntax error, (missing operator) did this work for you?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I forgot that you need to use 'AS' with MS access, I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH
  a AS (
    SELECT
      os.Order_ID,
      os.order_status_id AS Order_Status_ID,
      ms.status_description AS Status_Description,
      os.[Timestamp],
      c.Contact_time,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY os.Order_ID
        ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
      ) AS rn
    FROM Contact AS c
    JOIN Order_Status AS os
      ON c.Order_id = os.Order_ID AND
         c.Contact_time >= os.[Timestamp]
    LEFT JOIN meta_status AS ms
      ON os.order_status_id = ms.order_status_id
  )
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Result:

```
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----+
| Order_ID | Order_Status_ID | Status_Description |        Timestamp        |      Contact_time       | rn |
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----+
|        1 |               3 | desc3              | 2019-12-24 00:10:00.000 | 2019-12-24 00:25:00.000 |  1 |
|        2 |               9 |                    | 2019-12-24 15:10:00.000 | 2019-12-24 15:30:00.000 |  1 |
|        4 |               3 | desc3              | 2019-12-24 19:32:00.000 | 2019-12-24 19:38:00.000 |  1 |
|        5 |               2 | desc2              | 2019-01-28 19:30:00.000 | 2019-01-28 19:46:00.000 |  1 |
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----+
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=90fffe5caaa2a713641eeed56955d311)